# How can I stop Kafka from retrying connections?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a structured streaming application that reads messages from Kafka and then shuts down. However, if the kafka broker is down or unreachable, my application will attempt to reconnect indefinitely. I would prefer that it shuts down after 2-3 retries and let my orchestration engine handle alerting and retrying.

It seems like Kafka does not expose any configuration options on the consumer side that would allow us to stop attempting reconnects after a certain time period or retry count.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/6ab4d047d563e0fe42a7c0ed6f10ddecda135595/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.java

The only configurations that I found in the ConsumerConfig that might assist us with this are the following:

```
kafka.reconnect.backoff.ms
kafka.reconnect.backoff.max.ms
kafka.socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms
```

Here is my Structured Streaming code for reference:

```
val checkpointUrl = "s3://mybucket/experiment/checkpoint/"
val url = "s3://mybucket/experiment/triggerOnce/"

val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "X.X.X.X:9092")
  .option("kafka.reconnect.backoff.max.ms", 1000)
  .option("kafka.socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms", 10000)
  .option("subscribe", "experiment3")
  .load()
  .writeStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointUrl)
  .trigger(Trigger.Once())
  .start(url)
  .awaitTermination()
```

I am currently looking into if there is a way to leverage SparkListeners to intervene within the reconnection logic.

Comment: I don't think you can stop it. That's not how the Kafka Consumer API works. You could instead create a Kafka native `AdminClient` and **use that** to test connection before even trying to start the Spark stream

Comment: Yea, I think you're right. There doesn't seem to be a way to stop it. The adminClient approach might be our best bet at the moment. Thanks